# Django-allauth Third-Party Login Failure

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views, django-allauth

I've got an instance of an application where I'm trying to authenticate users using Google/Github. All the configuration is as documented, the callbacks are as required by the docs, the client ID and secrets are alright.

Yet, when receiving the callback, I get shown the following page

The callback url i am getting is (with no error msg):

http://localhost:8000/accounts/github/login/callback/?code=1216195be45faf4d04af&state=jYUTOFAXVKeiqzpk

I do not know what code and state in uri is referring to.

[The page I am getting redirected to after login attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Ogr.png)

I was using version `0.61.1`

Downgrading to `0.54.0` and removing `allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware` middleware solved the problem. But now I can not use LinkedIn Open ID Connect authentication as it is not supported in version `0.54.0`.

Looking for the solution so that i can use **google,github, and linkedin** social auth in version `0.61.1`

Answer (score 0):

Good day!
I found this information and it helps me.
You need to modify it in you admin site. Django-allauth "client" code it is "appid".

When I changed it "client" to the appid using the Django admin, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and it happened because I missed a letter while providing the **client_secret**. So try checking the credentials to see if you missed anything.